# How to get distinct route in SQL?

Tags: sql, subquery, window-functions

For the table below (The data type of each column is varchar):

[image]

The RouteId R1 and R4, the route DelhiBombay, and BombayDelhi will be considered the same route.
How can I get distinct routes from the above table?
Or create a new column, which has the same value for R1 and R4

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: is it necessary that "distinct_route_id" is an incrementing integer?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt preferably yes, but no not necessary, just that the same routes should have same the same id

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

```
        select t1.route_id,
               t1.source,
               t1.destination,
               t2.route_id as same_route
          from your_table t1
     left join your_table t2 on t1.source = t2.destination and t1.destination = t2.source
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the distinct routes with `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.source = t.destination
        and t1.destination = t.source
        and t1.destination > t1.source
)
```

On the other hand, you can assign route numbers with `dense_rank()`; if your database supports `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
select
    t.*,
    dense_rank() over(order by least(source, destination), greatest(source, destination)) rn
from mytable t
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. I understood your logic and both the solutions solve my problem. but I prefer the 2nd, where you used least() and greatest(), it gives me exactly what I needed. But I am using SQL Server and they do not support these functions. But your 2nd solution gave an idea and was able to solve it. Thanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

```
#tabel_name = city_route 

select
Route_id,
source,
destination,
concat('D',dense_rank() over (order by s,d)) distinct_route_id
from (
    select c1.*,source s,destination d
    from city_route c1
    where source > destination
    union all
    select c2.*,destination,source
    from city_route c2
    where source < destination
    )a
order by len(route_id),route_id
```